# Monitoring of Spring Batch application deployed in EC2. Options?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, spring-batch

I have the Spring Boot application with the @EnableBatchProcessing annotation working locally.

I disabled the embedded Tomcat because I am not serving any pages via REST.

We want to deploy this app in the EC2/AWS. I am confused on how to monitor the health of the batch program in Production. I see 3 possible design options:

1. Use Spring Actuator. I can re-enable the embedded tomcat and use Actuator for health checks. But, since this app is a batch program, doesn't have any functional RestController would this make sense?
2. I can change the design and call the job from Web Container as described here, than Actuator makes seems logical:
   https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer

And call the URL via curl from a scheduler like Autosys instead of using the CRON annotation to run it on scheduler automatically.

3. Can change the design and use the **@EnableScheduling** annotation and **@Scheduled(cron="*/10 * * * * *")** on the method to schedule the jobs automatically instead of calling them via endpoint.

But how will I monitor the health of this app in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In this case i think you can use prometheus/grafana, prometheus will get the metrics from actuator then you can use grafana queries to check what ever you want as you can see in the picture.

[image]

Actuator will return you the metrics of spring batch, health (up/down), thread pool..., you will have to check this by queries like the second pic.

[image]

Hope this could help you.